# How to show remaining time of downloading and total file size in browser?

Tags: php, file, download, readfile, filesize

I have this code:

```
$file="http://domain/path/file.flv?hash=hashcode";

header('Content-Type: video/x-flv');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myvideo.flv' );

readfile($file);
```

And when I access download.php it starts downloading, and in the browser shows:

1 KB, 2 KB, ... 1MB, 2MB, ....

What I want to know is how to show the text below in the browser when downloading the file, something like this:

2MB/29MB remaining 5 minutes...

I mean, at the bottom of the browser (where the file is downloading) - Chrome, or in the "Downloads" window - Firefox

I tryed this:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Here is the answer I sure that, It will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052208/unable-to-show-download-progress-of-file-from-new-server-worked-on-previous-ser#

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to control the way your browser shows uploading process, unfortunately you can't do it..

You may use an uploading library like http://www.uploadify.com/ to do it, and there you can control the way the upload looks.

Comment: No, that is not what I want. So, I wanna grab the right size of file from an url like: http://domain.com/path/videofile.flv?hash=somehashcode